# Breeding a Pachirisu with the volt absorb ability

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can I breed volt absorb from one female pokemon in the same egg group as Pachirisu directly to a male Pachirisu lacking the ability? And if so, where can I find pokemon with the hidden ability in pokemon oras/xy?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Volt Absorb has to come from another pachirisu. You can breed more either through a female pachirisu with the ability and any other male in its egg group, or a male pachirisu with the ability and a ditto.

You can catch Volt Absorb pachirisu through an electric friend safari in XY. Pachirisu is not available anywhere in ORAS except through trade.

Source: [bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pachirisu_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Game_locations).